# Projectile Motion Question involving a ball and a ramp inclined at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, projectile

The question is to finde the initial horizontal velocity of the ball at end of the ramp, where it is released.

I know how to do this using gravitational potential energy and kinetic energy ($v=\sqrt{2gh}$), assuming all potential energy is converted into kinetic energy but the question is asking me to find the error in the experiment.

It gives me the values on $y$ as the ramp is lifted up (it is lifted up about 10 cm each time) and the corresponding values of $x^2$. I drew a graph of $x^2$ vs $y$ and found the gradient.

How can I use this to find the experimental initial horizontal velocity?

This sketch shows what the experiment looks like: 
[image: Experiment]

Comment: Sorry, what are $x$ and $y$ in this context? Are they initial values? Or are they variables?

Comment: In this experiment the experimenter changes the value of y so it is an independent variable. As $y$ increases (the hight of the point of release of the ball, i.e. the hight of the ramp) the value of x and hence $x^2$ increase. If you draw a graph then the relationship is linear, i.e. the path is parabolic. From the gradient I know that $\frac{x^{2}}{y}=40$.

Comment: And what is $x$?

Comment: x is the horizontal distance between the end of the ramp and where the ball hits the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: ramp]
**Disclaimer:** Since this is a homework style problem, I'm not going to write all the details.

Writing down the projectile's equation, and replacing $\theta$ we arrive at the equation:

$$-\frac{x^2}{\frac{4 g (h-y) \left(l^2-(y-h)^2\right)}{l^2}}-\frac{x (y-h)}{\sqrt{l^2-(y-h)^2}}+h=0$$

Solving this for $x$, and simplifying the huge expressions(perhaps by something like Mathematica); we find:

$$x\to \frac{ \left( 2 \sqrt{g (h-y) (h+l-y)^2 (-h+l+y)^2 \left(g (h-y)^3+h l^2\right)}-2 g (h-y)^2 (h-l-y) (h+l-y)\right)}{l^2 \sqrt{-(h-l-y) (h+l-y)}}$$

Squaring:

$$\Rightarrow x^2=\frac{1}{l^4}4 g (y-h) \left(-2 h \sqrt{g (h-y) (h+l-y)^2 (-h+l+y)^2 \left(g (h-y)^3+h l^2\right)}+2 y \sqrt{g (h-y) (h+l-y)^2 (-h+l+y)^2 \left(g (h-y)^3+h l^2\right)}+2 g (h-y)^3 (h-l-y) (h+l-y)+h l^2 (h-l-y) (h+l-y)\right)$$

In general if we have a function of several independent parameters(i.e. $f(x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n)$), and we want to calculate the error in $f$, we would write:

$$\delta f = \sqrt{\sum_i \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\delta x_i \right)^2}$$

In this case $x^2$ only depens on $y$, and its error comes from the error in $y$:

$$\delta (x^2) = \left| \frac{\partial (x^2)}{\partial y} \delta y\right| = x^2 \left|\frac{ \left(-g (h-y)^3 \left(3 (h-y)^2-l^2\right)+3 h \sqrt{g (h-y) (h+l-y)^2 (-h+l+y)^2 \left(g (h-y)^3+h l^2\right)}-3 y \sqrt{g (h-y) (h+l-y)^2 (-h+l+y)^2 \left(g (h-y)^3+h l^2\right)}+h l^2 \left(l^2-3 (h-y)^2\right) \right)}{(h-y) (h-l-y) (h+l-y) \left(g (h-y)^3+h l^2\right)}  \delta y\right|$$

It doesn't even fit properly! Anyway, putting back all the corresponding numbers, we find:

$$\frac{\delta (x^2)}{x^2} \approx 0.52 \delta y$$

Which looks like a decent result to me. Note, this final equation is only true for values given in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjtZn.png), namely $h=9.7 \text{cm}, y=17.5 \text{cm}, l=60\text{cm} \ \text{and}\  g=980 \text{cm}\text{.s}^{-2}$.

Comment: Wow, sledge hammer :P But thank you, really appreciate it! I found a much simpler way to do it, not sure if it agrees with your working.

Comment: Sorry, but I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: Is it? If I sub the given values I get the required answer. Could you please tell me which part is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Vertically:

$\ddot{y}=a$

$\frac{d\dot{y}}{dt}=a\therefore \int d\dot{y}=\int adt\therefore \dot{y}=u\sin\theta +at$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=u\sin\theta +at\therefore \int dy=\int \left ( u\sin\theta +at \right )dt\therefore y=u\sin\theta t+\frac{a}{2}t^{2}$

Horizontally:

$\ddot{x}=0$

$\frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}=0\therefore \int d\dot{x}=\int 0dt\therefore \dot{x}=u\cos\theta$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=u\cos\theta\therefore x=u\cos\theta t$

We know the gradient of the graph of $\frac{x^{2}}{y}=m$ ($m$ is the gradient, measured in $cm$)
Sub $x=u\cos\theta t$ and $y=\frac{a}{2}t^{2}$

$\therefore u\cos\theta=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{a}{2}m}{100}}m/s$

Theoretically, $u\cos\theta$ can be found by considering the conversion of gravitational potential energy to kinetic energy, assuming no energy loses

$\therefore mah=\frac{1}{2}m\left (u\cos\theta   \right )^{2}\therefore u\cos\theta=\sqrt{2ah}$

Comment: Look, as you said in the comments of the post, $y$ is the height of the ramp; so probably  $\ddot y \ne a$, it's rather zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is an 'error' in your reasoning. The velocity of the ball at the end of the ramp is **not** given by $v=\sqrt{2gh}$. This assumes that the ball **slides** down the ramp. Presumably it **rolls** and gains rotational as well as translational kinetic energy. If the ball has uniform density and rolls without slipping then the velocity after [rolling down an incline](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/sphinc.html) is $v=\sqrt{\frac{10}{7}gh}$, which is smaller. If the ramp is quite steep there could be a mixture of rolling and sliding, so the launch velocity will be somewhere in between the two values.